# How to create annotation using PdfSharp to highlight text of existing PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I would like know whether it is possible to create an text highlight annotation in an existing PDF using PdfSharp?

In the PdfSharp [documentation](http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Annotations-sample.ashx), I see examples of `PdfTextAnnotation` & `PdfRubberStampAnnotation`, but did not find sample code for following annotations mentioned in the documentation.

```
PdfLineAnnotation, PdfSquareAnnotation, PdfCircleAnnotation, 
PdfMarkupAnnotation, PdfHighlightAnnotation, PdfUnderlineAnnotation,
PdfSquigglyAnnotation, PdfSoundAnnotation, PdfMovieAnnotation.
```

Are these annotations yet to be implemented in PdfSharp? If someone has already implemented, please point me to the code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced with such problem and I didn't find any additional annotation types at the PdfSharp library. So I looked at the article "12.5 Annotations" from the [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). For example, it says that to create a text markup annotation a developer need to specify the `Subtype` and `QuadPoints` entries. Please see the source code below.

```
namespace PdfSharp.Pdf.Annotations
{
    using Extensions;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class PdfHighlightAnnotation : PdfMarkupAnnotation
    {
        public PdfHighlightAnnotation()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public PdfHighlightAnnotation(PdfDocument document)
            : base(document)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            Elements.SetName(Keys.Subtype, "/Highlight");
        }
    }

    public class PdfStrikeOutAnnotation : PdfMarkupAnnotation
    {
        public PdfStrikeOutAnnotation()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public PdfStrikeOutAnnotation(PdfDocument document)
            : base(document)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            Elements.SetName(Keys.Subtype, "/StrikeOut");
        }
    }

    public abstract class PdfMarkupAnnotation : PdfAnnotation
    {
        protected PdfMarkupAnnotation()
        { }

        protected PdfMarkupAnnotation(PdfDocument document)
            : base(document)
        { }

        public IEnumerable<PdfRectangle> Quadrilaterals
        {
            set {
                var points = new PdfArray();
                foreach (var r in value) {
                    points.Elements.AddRange(ToQuadPoints(r));
                }
                Elements.SetValue("/QuadPoints", points);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<PdfItem> ToQuadPoints(PdfRectangle r)
        {
            // Conversion from PdfRectangle coordinates
            //
            // Y ^
            //   |                     (X2 Y2)
            //   |        +-----------+
            //   |        |           |
            //   |        |           |
            //   |        +-----------+
            //   | (X1 Y1)
            //   |                              
            //   +-----------------------------> 
            //                                 X
            // to QuadPoints coordinates (x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4)
            //
            // Y ^
            //   | (x4 y4)             (x3 y3)
            //   |        +-----------+
            //   |        |           |
            //   |        |           |
            //   |        +-----------+
            //   | (x1 y1)             (x2 y2)
            //   |                              
            //   +-----------------------------> 
            //                                 X
            //
            return new List<PdfItem> { new PdfReal(r.X1), new PdfReal(r.Y1),
                                       new PdfReal(r.X2), new PdfReal(r.Y1),
                                       new PdfReal(r.X1), new PdfReal(r.Y2),
                                       new PdfReal(r.X2), new PdfReal(r.Y2)};
        }
    }
}

namespace PdfSharp.Extensions
{
    using PdfSharp.Pdf;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class ArrayElementsExtensions
    {
        public static void AddRange(this PdfArray.ArrayElements elements, IEnumerable<PdfItem> values)
        {
            foreach (var v in values) {
                elements.Add(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, but how to use it? I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Would you be able to help me on how to use this code. I can't get to working

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple times and follow up with pdfsharp forum. I got the solution. Happy Coding!!
Original Question and Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049007/2032722)

```
private static void AddAnnotation(XGraphics graphics, PdfPage page, double x, double y, double height, double width)
{
    PdfSharp.Drawing.XRect rect = graphics.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(new XPoint(x, y), new XSize(width, height)));
    XRect annotrect = new XRect(new XPoint(x, y), new XSize(width, height));
    // Create a PDF text annotation
    PdfTextAnnotation textAnnot = new PdfTextAnnotation();
    textAnnot.Title = "This is the title";
    textAnnot.Subject = "This is the subject";
    textAnnot.Contents = "This is the contents of the annotation.\rThis is the 2nd line.";            
    textAnnot.Rectangle = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfRectangle(rect);
    // The following lines of code did the trick
    textAnnot.Elements.Remove("/Subtype");
    textAnnot.Elements.Add("/Subtype", new PdfLiteral("/Square"));
    textAnnot.Elements.Add("/IC", new PdfLiteral("[0 0 0]"));
    textAnnot.Elements.Add("/CA", new PdfLiteral("0"));

    // Add the annotation to the page
    page.Annotations.Add(textAnnot);
}
```

Comment: pdfsharp is not friendly then. users need to be abstracted from memorizing such things for at least even simple type annotations such as this one.