# iTextsharp/itext7 - Not able to pop up the annotation when hovering on the rectangle

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am working with iText7 c# library to highlight the text and add annotations when mouse hover on the highlighted text.

I would like to annotate a rectangular area/highlighted text on my PDF. i.e. I would like to hover the mouse anywhere within the given rectangle area and have the annotation pop up.

It seems that a Text annotation only appears when hovering in the upper left corner of the annotation Rectangle. I tried using the combination of Rectangle and Text Annotation but that only seems to pop up when I'm hovering over the top left corner not the interior.

Can you tell me how to have the annotation appear when I hover anywhere within the given Rectangle?

> I tried with changing the Rectangle size but, no luck..

> FYI, I was able to achieve the same functionality with [Pdfsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69018050/pdfsharp-unable-to-pop-up-the-annotation-when-hovering-on-the-rectangle/69049007#69049007)

**PDFSharp Output**
[image]

**iText7 Output**

> The Annotation pops up only when we mouse hover on the borders

[image]

> The output PDF link is [here](https://github.com/gowtham-kunduru/pdfGenerationPoc)

Thank you in advance

Comment: **A** What is your current code resulting in the non-satisfying result? **B** Can you share output PDFs both from your iText code and your PdfSharp code for analysis?

Comment: @mkl **A** Added images of the results, **B** updated question with links, available on git-hub https://github.com/gowtham-kunduru/pdfGenerationPoc **C** Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pdfSharpOutput.pdf` has set the **IC** (interior color) but not the **C** ((border) color).
Your `iText7Output.pdf` has not set the **IC** (interior color) but the **C** ((border) color).

Apparently Adobe Acrobat only displays that hover text for areas for which a color has been defined. (This behavior is arbitrary, it is not in any way prescribed by the standard. Thus, it may change in any new release of Acrobat.)

To get the same behavior with iText as with PdfSharp, you should set the interior color of the iText `PdfSquareAnnotation` using one of its `setInteriorColor` overloads.

Comment: I am not able to set the Opacity for the InteriorColor I tried with `squareAnnotation.SetInteriorColor(new float[] { (float)0.294, (float)0.552, (float)0.968 });
            squareAnnotation.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(30));
            squareAnnotation.SetStrokingOpacity(25);
            squareAnnotation.SetNonStrokingOpacity(25);` none of them worked. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please make that a question in its own right and share your pivotal code for creating and adding that annotation.

Comment: sure, here is the original question posted just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285245/itext7-unable-to-set-the-the-opacity-for-squareannotation-interior-color

Comment: Just checking.. Did you get a chance to look at the question. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I haven't had the time yet. (The answer is not obvious to me, so I have to do some tests before answering.)

Comment: @DangerousDev Ok, I just answered the question. It was simple after all.