# iText7 - unable to set the the Opacity for SquareAnnotation Interior color

Tags: c#, itext, .net-5, itext7

Team,
I am working with iText7 C# library. I am not able to set the Opacity for the Square Annotation InteriorColor.

Below is the code I am using. I tried with all the different methods we have for a SquareAnnotation to set the Opacity but, no luck. am I missing anything?

```
private PdfSquareAnnotation AddAnnotation(float rectHeight, float rectWidth, float x, float y)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        PdfSquareAnnotation squareAnnotation = new PdfSquareAnnotation(rect);
        squareAnnotation.SetColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
        squareAnnotation.SetTitle(new PdfString("This is the title"));
        squareAnnotation.SetContents("This is the contents of the annotation. bla bla..");
        squareAnnotation.SetNonStrokingOpacity(25);
        squareAnnotation.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(30));
        squareAnnotation.SetInteriorColor(new float[] { (float)0.294, (float)0.552, (float)0.968 });

        //squareAnnotation.SetStrokingOpacity(25);


        return squareAnnotation;
    }
```

**Output:**

> Opacity for interior color is not being applied

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that you use opacity values 25 and 30 - the opacity value range is 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque). Thus, 25 and 30 effectively are *excessively opaque*.

By switching to

```
squareAnnotation.SetNonStrokingOpacity(0.25f);
squareAnnotation.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(0.30f));
```

you get the desired partial transparency.